# why can't I see the collaborator invite?

Tags: github, repo

I invited my colleague to a repo, he didn't receive it. am trying to cancel the invite and re-invite him again.

It does show ["1 Invitation"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsFIP.png). but when I click on it to manage it, it shows [nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO1hL.png).

and whenever I try to invite him again, it says ["User has already been invited"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQruP.png).

so I am stuck not being able to cancel the invite nor re-invite him.